# Image blinking when loading from localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

In chrome, when I set src of image to be something on my local machine, image blinks when I reload, or get back to page. It seems that browser is not caching images or something. If I load image from some external site, it works ok.

Also works in firefox in both cases.

Does anyone knows what cause of problem?

Thank you

Comment: ctrl+shift+j then go to network tab, see if the image was loaded from cache in the size column

Comment: no, it isn't. It is loading picture again from server

Comment: just to confirm... is that a static image? what is your server?

Comment: yes...just normal .jpg image hosted on node.js locally

Comment: in opera also works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was because maxAge header was set to 0.